# java printing different answers

Tags: java, string

**EXPECTATION**
I want my code to first, find a gene by using the start codon "ATG" and stop codon "TAA" if TAA orATG are mising to retun a blank string. Code should then,check if Gene is divisible by 3 and therefore a true gene then print result. I want to test code using void testFindSimpleGene.

**REALITY**
ALL genes printed are blank strings and each blank string is printed everal times

public class findSimpleGeneAndTest {

```
public String findSimpleGene(String dna) {
    String result = "";
    int startIndex = dna.indexOf("ATG");//start codon is ATG 
        if( startIndex == -1){ //If there is no ATG return empty srting
            return ""; 
        }         
        int stopIndex = dna.indexOf("TAA", startIndex+3); //stop codon is TAA
        if( stopIndex ==-1){ //If there is no TAA return empty srting
            return "";
        }
        if ((stopIndex+3)-startIndex %3 != 0){ //Test that gene divisable by 3; a true gene
           return "";
        }
    result = dna.substring(startIndex, stopIndex+3);
    return result;
}

public void testFindSimpleGene(){
    String dna = "AATGCGTAATATGGT";
    System.out.println("DNA strand is " + dna);
    String gene = findSimpleGene(dna);
    System.out.println("Gene is "+gene);

    dna = "AATGCTAGGGTAATATGGT";
    System.out.println("DNA strand is " + dna);
    gene = findSimpleGene(dna);
    System.out.println("Gene is "+ gene);

    dna = "ATCCTATGCTTCGGCTGCTCTAATATGGT";
    System.out.println("DNA strand is " + dna);
    gene = findSimpleGene(dna);
    System.out.println("Gene is " + gene);

    dna = "ATGTAA";
    System.out.println("DNA strand is " + dna);
    gene = findSimpleGene(dna);
    System.out.println("Gene is " + gene);

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some complementary debugging techniques. If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` (modulo)  has higher precedence than `-` (minus), so your expression is evaluated as:

```
(stopIndex + 3) - (startIndex % 3)
```

I think you meant to do:

```
((stopIndex + 3) - startIndex) % 3
```

Which can be shortened to

```
(stopIndex - startIndex) % 3
```

Comment: Nice, precise, concise. Perfect.